# SQL Command To Trim Output

Tags: sql-server

I need to rip out the digits of a number i'm returning.  I have them in a listing like X0006, X0130, and X1030.  I need to pull out X's and 0's and return 6,130,1030 . I've tried RTRIM like this.  Anyone have any ideas on what I need to do?  I'm sure i'm missing something easy.

Thanks

Comment: substring is your choice http://www.dailyfreecode.com/Code/substring-function-292.aspx

Comment: @bksi If he used substring to remove0's wouldn't it remove the 0's from inside a number, such as 1030?

Comment: @intelwalk, wil there always be an X in the front of the string?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(CAST(REPLACE('X00123', 'X', '') AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10))`

Comment: Adding to what @Elias asked, are you trying to parse a single string containing "X0006, X0130, X1030" or "X0006", "X0130", and "X1030" as separate strings?

Comment: separate strings, the won't be together or in the same row.

Comment: I used replace to get rid of the X and just copied/pasted into excel to get the preceding zeros off.

Comment: Did you try @T I's answer? I believe his implicitly Removes the 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used replace to get rid of the X and just copied/pasted into excel to get the preceding zeros off

Answer (score 1):

Use replace to convert X and O to empty strings, cast to a integer to remove leading zeros.

Sample code below.

```
-- Simple number table
create table #nums
( my_id int identity(1,1),
  my_text varchar(32)
);

-- Simplte test data
insert into #nums (my_text)
values
('X10X30X'),
('O00O30O');


-- Remove characters & convert to int
SELECT CAST (REPLACE(REPLACE(my_text, 'X', ''), 'O', '') AS INT) as my_number 
FROM #nums
```

Sample output below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can create that will do exactly what you're asking for and any future get digits needs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn__getDigits] 
( 
@string VARCHAR(50) 
) 
RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN 
-- declare variables 
DECLARE 
@digits VARCHAR(50), 
@length INT, 
@index INT, 
@char CHAR(1) 

-- initialize variables 
SET @digits = '' 
SET @length = LEN(@string) 
SET @index = 0 

-- examine each character 
WHILE (@length >= @index) 
BEGIN 
SET @char = SUBSTRING(@string, @index, 1) 
SET @index = @index + 1 

-- add to the result if the character is a digit 
IF (48 <= ASCII(@char) AND ASCII(@char) <= 57) 
BEGIN 
SET @digits = @digits + @char 
END 
END 

-- return the result 
RETURN cast(@digits as int)
END
GO


select [dbo].[fn__getDigits]('X0006')
select [dbo].[fn__getDigits]('X0130')
select [dbo].[fn__getDigits]('X1030')
```

Comment: I think iterative solutions are frowned upon in T-SQL.  Don't tell me you use cursors for large updates!